# overriding not liked by the compiler

Tags: java, netbeans, overriding, java-6

I use jdk 6.

I have an interface:

```
    public interface DisplayValueListener<P>  {

         ...

         void setDisplayValue(P value, String reprValue);
    }
```

I have an abstract class named Widget that implements DisplayValueListener and is declared like this:

```
    public abstract class Widget<P> implements DisplayValueListener<P> {

        ...

        @Override
        public void setDisplayValue(final Object value, final String reprValue) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I also have another abstract class that extends Widget like this:

```
    public abstract class CameraWidget extends Widget<Void> {

        ...

        @Override
        public void setDisplayValue(final Void value, final String reprValue) {
        }
    }
```

This is the message that I get from the compiler in NetBeans:

name clash: setDisplayValue(Void,String) in CameraWidget overrides a method whose erasure is the same as another method, yet neither overrides the other first method:  setDisplayValue(Object,String) in Widget
second method: setDisplayValue(P,String) in DisplayValueListener
where P is a type-variable: P extends Object declared in interface DisplayValueListener

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and why the compiler in Eclipse (same jdk 6) is happy with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the generic parameter P in class Widget when you override the method:

```
 @Override
 public void setDisplayValue(final P value, final String reprValue) {
     ...
 }
```

Eclipse uses an own Java compiler and not javac and sometimes these two compilers interpret the Java spec differently.